# Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS preserving old redirections with apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect with apache server all the traffic from http to https. And I want to preserve my actual redirections (without www -> with www)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

With this htaccess I have http->https redirections and without www->with www redirection, but don't both at the same time.

I need this redirection:

`http://domain.com` -> `https://www.domain.com`

`http://domain.com/foo/bar` -> `https://www.domain.com/foo/bar`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[OR]` clause to combine the 2 conditions in a single redirect rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Now if you want to avoid hardcoding domain name in this rule then use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Clear your browser cache before testing this change.